# How to disable Kube-DNS on GKE

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kube-dns

I have a CoreDNS running in our cluster that uses the Kube DNS service. I want to disable the AutoScaler and the Kube-DNS deployment or scale it to 0.

As soon as I do this, however, it is always automatically scaled up to 2. What can I do?

Comment: Hello @n00dle. How exactly did you try to disable/scale to 0? Which commands/methods have you tried?

Comment: I have scaled both deployments to 0. (Autoscaler and KubeDNS)
"kubectl scale deploy kubedns --replicas=0"

Answer (score 2):

The scenario you are going through is described by the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/custom-kube-dns).

- Make sure that you created your custom CoreDNS as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/custom-kube-dns#creating_a_custom_deployment).
- Disable the kube-dns managed by GKE by scaling the kube-dns Deployment and autoscaler to zero using the following command:

---

```
kubectl scale deployment --replicas=0 kube-dns-autoscaler --namespace=kube-system
kubectl scale deployment --replicas=0 kube-dns --namespace=kube-system
```

---

- If the above command will still not work than try the following one:

---

```
kubectl scale --replicas=0 deployment/kube-dns-autoscaler --namespace=kube-system 

kubectl scale --replicas=0 deployment/kube-dns --namespace=kube-system
```

---

Remember to specify the `namespace`.

Comment: If the above suggestion will still not work for you than please let me know so we could dig deeper.

Comment: The Custom Kube-DNS runs with me, nevertheless after the scaling the normal kube-dns pods come again and again.

But the autoscaler will not start up again. So I am one step closer to the goal.

Comment: Hello @n00dle. Any further progress? Have you tried to manually change replicas to 0 via the yaml config?